# iPhone: Auto Layout Not Working

Tags: iphone, ios, autolayout

I have a problem with autolayout. The Table View below the Image View should resize to fill the whole space below when the App runs on an iPhone 5, but it doesn't. What is the problem?

[image]

Comment: Are the cells not filling the tableview, or is the space below the tableview just empty? Set a `backgroundColor` on the view controller's `view` to see.

Comment: The cells are not filling the tableview. The problem is not below the cells, it is above the cells. When I run the app on iPhone 5 there is a space between the image view and the table view.

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot?

Comment: Yes, here it is: http://postimg.org/image/swn3jd6vl/

Comment: In ios7 everything is white so it's hard to tell where one view begins and the other ends. Try giving the imageView, the tableView and the view controller's view a different `backgroundColor`. That will show us which view is taking up that white space in the middle.

Comment: Image: http://postimg.org/image/s8vj0ez97/ The view is now colored green, the image view red and the table view blue. But the space in between is still white, so it looks like it belongs to the table view. I Have noticed that the problem isn't iphone 5 only, it is the same on iPhone 4 so I think it is not a Auto Layout problem, but I don't understand where the white space comes from, it is not the TableView Header.

Comment: It seems like the whitespace is the same height as the navigation bar plus status bar. Are you doing anything to pin the image view to the navigation bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table view should have a vertical spacing constraint to the image view and another one to the bottom of the screen. It should have no height constraint.

**After Edit:**

I'm not sure what all your constraints are. It seems that something needs a fixed height (or some way to tell the system what the relative heights of the image view and table view are). It worked fine for me to give the image view a fixed height, and with these constraints for the image view and table view:

image view:

[image]

table view:

[image]

Comment: I aready have the constraint to the bottom and the image view. I deleted the height constraint now but I didn't change anything.

Comment: @user2611144, Do both of the spacing constraints (to the image view and the bottom of the view) have a constant value of 0?

Comment: @user2611144, I updated my answer to show what worked for me.